# Spring message in javascript file

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying spring:message tag to my javascript file, but nothing is displayed. In jsp file and tag  spring:message works fine, but if I put js code to js file it's not working.

In js file I use:

```
password: '<spring:message code="account.enterPassword" />'
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring tags renders on the server side and javascript works in client after server side process is complete. But you can put an `<script></script>` tag inside your jsp, define your variable on it, and then access your `global javascript variable` in your external js file:

jsp:

```
<script>
    var password: '<spring:message code="account.enterPassword" />'
     //any other variables you want to use
</script>
```

Now, you can access the `password` variable inside any other js file.

Note, this script tag must be at top of your js files that you want to variables on it. Also, be careful when picking a name for global variables, because, local variables can override global variables in case of common name.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for javascript to have access to a spring tag. `spring:message` is processed server-side before the page is sent to the client, javascript/jQuery is processed later on the client side.

As a workaround, put the message value in a hidden input on your jsp page. Then get its value in your javascript. In your case:

```
<c:set var="val"><spring:message code="account.enterPassword"/></c:set>
<input id="enterPasswordId" type="hidden" value="${val}"/>
```

In your javascript (using jquery) you can then use it as follows:

```
$('#enterPasswordId').val() //jquery
document.getElementById("enterPasswordId"); //javascript
```